# Userform listbox that depends on another listbox

Tags: vba, excel, dependencies, logic

I have been looking in the internet for the answer to this, but mostly people say to use data validation, which doesn't really solve my problem. What I'm trying to do is, lets say that I have ListBox1, which has 3 values (red, blue, green) and there's another listbox (ListBox2) where I want value of a list from a worksheet to appear depending on the answer of the first ListBox. For example: I select red from listbox1 and then I want to have the options from the list "red" (apple, coke,fire) in listbox2.
I would greatly appreciate some help in this. Thanks

Comment: You really should use data validation, though - see [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html) on how to use named ranges to achieve what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use something like follows (adapt it as per your needs):

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    With Me.ListBox2
        .Clear
        .List = Application.Transpose(GetColorItemsRange(Me.ListBox1.value)) 'fill referenced listbox with values from the range returned by GetColorItemsRange function
    End With
End Sub

Function GetColorItemsRange(colorValue As String) As Range
    With Worksheets("ColorItames") ' change "ColorItames" with actual name of your worksheet with items associated to colors
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Find(what:=colorValue, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) 'find and reference the referenced sheet row 1 cell matching the passed value
            Set GetColorItemsRange = .Parent.Range(.Cells.Offset(1), .Cells.End(xlDown)) 'return the range ranging from referenced range down to last not empty cell before first empty cell
        End With
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Data validation is the way to go. You would want to leverage some combination of VBA to adjust the range listbox2 is using after Listbox1 is updated. This is *relatively* easy if only 1 selection is used on listbox1.

Hopefully you just have one selection, so you could do the following code:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

If ListBox1.Selected(0) = True Then
    'Selection is apple. Adjust DynamicRange name for A1:A3
    ThisWorkbook.Names("DynamicRange").RefersTo = Range("A1:A3")

ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(1) = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.Names("DynamicRange").RefersTo = Range("B1:B3")

ElseIf ListBox1.Selected(2) = True Then
    ThisWorkbook.Names("DynamicRange").RefersTo = Range("C1:C3")

End If

End Sub
```

This is based on a setup that looks like this:[image]

Here's what both listbox properties would look like:

[image]

If you want to download this classy template, [click here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TIeuIeQNdKay5rABa2Y-p7QN5WPAZIfn/view?usp=sharing)